# RED Robot Editor - Is there anyway to execute multiple testsuites parallelly?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-grid

I have 7 testsuites that are specific to languages something like German, Finish, Italy etc., I would like to execute all at one time. Kindly provide me solution on this. Referred to many materials, but having confusions that how we should work with RED Editor.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only possibility to add parallel execution to robot tests is to

- parallelize code inside python classes or
- make each test suite a
  separate test call (i.e. with ctest execution) and call several of
  them separately (ctest -j)

RIDE does not provide this, nor does robotframework natively.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent releases of RED it is possible to use a custom script to launch robot from RED. The documentation shows some examples in the [Launch Scripting section](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/local_launch_scripting.html). In the section about launching using Gradle there is a nice [Windows batch example](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/tools_integration/gradle.html).

This could be used to have RED launch [Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) to run several Robot sessions in parallel. This would allow you to achieve the parallelisation from RED you seek.

The Selenium Grid can help with this, but I'd consider it if the testing load needs to be spread across multiple machines. If only running locally, then pabot itself is sufficient.